# How to curve a flat object?

Tags: bezier-curves

Tried searching but couldn't find how to curve this in  the way I show with red lines (ms paint, sry XD)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way your slab is oriented (relative to your reference sketch), you will need to rotate the Empty that controls your Modifier 90° on the X axis. This is because the Simple Deform Modifier bends about the axis object's Z axis.

Then set your Deform Angle to 90 or -90, depending on which way you want it to curve.

Finally, use the Limits sliders to specify where the bending influence will begin and end.

[image: Simple Deform Modifier - Bend using Limits sliders]

Answer (score 3):

Add an Empty, with rotation=90 (may be X or Y depending on the orientation of your slab).

[image]

Next, add a Simple Deform modifier to the slab, using the Empty as the Axis,Origin object:

[image]